# How to pull out schema of db from MySQL/phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database, schema, phpmyadmin, export

is there some way of pulling out the schema of your mysql databases?

I have lots of db and tables inside these databases, and I use phpmyadmin with WAMP in my local machine.

I need to pull out the schema, or atleast the database name, table name, columns and their attributes (e.g. `INT(2)`) and export it as csv/ excel/ whatever format which finally can be edited in excel.

i use:

**server:**

```
    Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8
    MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $
    PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
```

**mysql:**

```
    Server: localhost (localhost via TCP/IP)
    Server version: 5.5.16-log
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want. You can try one of these methods:

**1)** Use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net)'s export feature to export the database. PMA allows you to omit the data so get all `CREATE TABLE` statements.

**2)** You can do the same using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). This command should export CREATE DATABASE/CREATE TABLE queries:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -proot --all-databases --no-data > create-database-and-tables.sql
```

**3)** You can pull information from mySQL schema tables. Most mySQL clients (phpMyAdmin, HeidiSQL etc) allow you to export result of queries as CSV. Some useful queries:

```
/*
 * DATABASE, TABLE, TYPE
 */
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql')
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE

/*
 * DATABASE, TABLE, COLUMN, TYPE
 */
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE /* ETC */
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql')
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: Your third option helped. I used the second query and then exported the results as csv and converted it to excel. Now I have details of all the tables with their column names and field settings. Thanks!

Comment: Yep - Second query let me get exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysqldump` from the console, e.g.

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u user -p -d -r dump.sql db_name
```

The `-d` switch makes `mysqldump` to dump the schema only, `-r` directs output to a given file.  You can also use `-X` to write dump in XML format.

Comment: thanks. the dumping worked. but where is it stored, and in the above case, what format is the output in? I use wamp server. mysql is in c:\wamp\bin\mysql\

Comment: @arun: by default, the output goes to stdout. You can use `-r file_name` to direct it to a file. The format is SQL

Comment: umm... i dont want the sql as such. what i am looking for is just the table structure, with column names, and in an excel format. is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

In the PhpMyAdmin's Export tab for the database, you want:

1. Check the box : Custom - display all possible options.
   [image: Step 1]
2. Under Format-specific options: section, choose Structure only
   [image: Step 2]