# Deploying a small PHP + MySQL service

Tags: php, mysql, sql, deployment, create-table

I am deploying a small PHP + MySQL service to my client and would like to know what is the proper way to set up the database:

- Should I use the hosting provider control panel and create the database schema?
- Or should I put SQL `CREATE` scripts in my PHP to run during the "init phase"? Do hosting providers even allow PHP to create tables?

It's a really small site, one tiny info page and one web service page for fetching data from the database.

Comment: Are you worried about copyright and Scott Adams?

Comment: @Ed: this is a Creative Commons site, I believe I can get away with "fair use". :-P

Comment: @d - I think that you might be on shaky ground - just wanted to point that out before the lawyers get involved. You are using both the name and the artwork. Also this site is for programmers to help each other, is that creative?

Comment: @Ed: I thought you were kidding the first time, lol. No, seriously, what are you talking about? Am I (or anyone here) seeing any financial gain from choosing this avatar over a different one? Have you browsed through the Users section recently? Am I really the only one using a "copyrighted" image around here? I think you are taking Internet a bit too seriously.

Comment: To conclude: no, I am not worried about Scott Adams. He is a great comic artist, I respect his work, read his comic and enjoy it that much that I decided to use his creation as my avatar. I doubt it will get me in trouble, but if it will keep you up at night, feel free to report this blatant rudeness of mine wherever you think it's appropriate.

Comment: @d - United media might have a different view on the subject. American companies can be litigious. Just pointing that out for your benefit. Also I do like Scott Adams work, but would also get annoyed if somebody used my work without permission or license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually offload all deployment tasks into an install script. This way you can deploy in a matter of seconds, and can repeat if necessary. I do not know of a way to restrict scripts from database modifications (other than mysql user permissions, which will typically be defined by you)

Comment: Great, that's how I usually work also. This is however my first time using a free PHP+mySQL hosting provider, so I was unsure about the usual way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend what your hosting provider offers - personally I would use the control panel which should at least provide phpMyAdmin. You can then export your schema from your development database and import it to the live version.

Comment: Export is a good idea, yes. But I seem to be inclined towards a hand-written script, because it's simpler to keep in my source control. Perhaps I can be lazy, set everything up in phpMyAdmin, and then export it.

Comment: Export your schema from phpMyAdmin and save it somewhere under source control, no need for re-writing the schema by hand - but knock yourself out if that's what you want to do! ;) This question addresses a similar topic to yours - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7991989/664125.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hosting provider you get a number of databases. Worst is 1 database, with a fixed name, most do 5 or more, with the ability to create your own database name. Often with a prefix.

I would go for the panel from the hoster, all though you can give any SQL statement through PHP.

Comment: Yes, I cannot create databases from PHP, and the db name must have a fixed prefix. But I can choose to create tables in my PHP if I see they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Why add the complication of PHP for the installation?

Just use raw SQL. Simpler. Fire that into the database.

Use PHP for the interface. Creating tables/stored procedures/triggers etc is a one off event.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense also. Although wrapping SQL into a PHP file takes only a couple of extra lines of code.

Comment: Really? A whole bunch of SQL to create tables, triggers etc. Please supply the code to do this as I am interested in your solution.